# Generate Specific ID using Cell values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im a noob in this so this is what i want to get done;

Im using Google Forms for customers to register and I need to give them Specific member IDs on the Google Sheet it self.

See how my sheet looks like:

[image: See how my sheet looks like]

When a new user registers them selves a New Row is added and the formula which i have is gone done due to the new Row added. I tried Freezing the Column but it didn't Work.

Im using

```
=CONCATENATE(D2," " ,B2)
```

to get the ID
What i'd love to get is something Like this,

[BRAND][Phone number without first two digits]
eg: DDT777717273

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Try using a single array formula in a cell `А1` `={"ID" ;ARRAYFORMULA (IF (D2:D<>"", D2:D&" " & B2:B,) )}`

Comment: Your post image does not show which column "Brand" is in.

Comment: @Sergey Wow Thank a lot it worked like a Charm... can you please help me out to omit the first two digits of the Phone number (Column D )

Comment: @erik-tyler 
I want to Use DDT its static  word

Comment: @KuruKumBa  I think this formula will help you `={"ID" ;ARRAYFORMULA (IF (D2:D<>"", regexreplace(TO_TEXT(D2:D),"^.{2}","")&" " & B2:B,) )}`